# Direct media library upload saving in wrong month date folder in custom theme

Tags: media, library

I have an issue in my custom theme.

Direct media library upload saving in wrong month date folder (2017/03) when current date is 2018/09. But when I upload images through post it goes to the correct folder.

I have tested in default theme, Direct media library upload goes to the correct folder. So the issue is in my custom theme. But I am not sure where to look at. In which file of my theme has the issue? Help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why my uploaded picture was loaded into /uploads/2015/02 not /uploads/2016/01?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213408/why-my-uploaded-picture-was-loaded-into-uploads-2015-02-not-uploads-2016-01)

Comment: Solution is not mentioned there. Please read my issue carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having may be related to [an issue in Wordpress core](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18408) that appears to affect a number of plugins. For context, see this [GiveWP plugin discussion](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/media-uploading-to-wrong-date/) and [issue](https://github.com/impress-org/givewp/issues/2830). In my experience, media uploaded from within a specific post is not affected.

Currently it looks like your options are a) tolerate the incorrect month/date, b) identify and remove the affected plugin/theme or c) update the plugin/theme to avoid using `the_post`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that in Settings > Media > Files upload > Save files uploaded in this folder: there's a URL that is not the default (wp-content/uploads).
Check this if it can help.